# Focus out an editable p tag with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have following html

```
<p contenteditable>The greatest p tag of all p tags all the time</p>
```

and this js

```
var p = document.querySelector('p');

p.addEventListner('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        //this.focusout() ??;
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sameerachathuranga/ben86foo/1/)**

But this thing doesn't work. How do i focusout the p tag with enter hit. No jquery Please. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misspelled `Listener` so the keypress wasn't being caught. You'll also want to prevent keypress like this

```js
var p = document.querySelector('p');
p.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        this.blur();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<p contenteditable>The greatest p tag of all p tags all the time</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct method for this is `.blur()`

So the following should suffice:

```
var p = document.querySelector('p');

p.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) { // you spelt addEventListener wrongly
    if (e.which === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();// to prevent the default enter functionality
        this.blur();            
    }
});
```

Comment: you just missed `e.preventDefault();` corrected that

Answer (score 3):

Try using `event.preventDefault()` , creating `input` element having `width` , `height` set to `0px` , `opacity` set to `0` . If `event.keyCode` equals `13` , call `.focus()` on `input` with `opacity` `0`

```js
var p = document.querySelector('p');

p.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("focus").focus();
  }
};
```

```css
#focus {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<p contentEditable>The greatest p tag of all p tags all the time</p>
<input id="focus" />
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ben86foo/10/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onblur` or `onfocusout` event:

```
<p onblur="myFunction()" contenteditable>
    The greatest p tag of all p tags all the time
</p>
```

or

```
<p onfocusout="myFunction()" contenteditable>
    The greatest p tag of all p tags all the time
</p>
```